# Jenkins with Kubernetes job pod gives not ready after 5000 MILLISECONDS error

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I'm getting an error of io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: not ready after 5000 MILLISECONDS

details:

**Environment**:

Jenkins version Jenkins 2.346.2 installed with helm

k8s plugin in jenkins version 3670.v6ca_059233222

Kubernetes in my Ubunut server:

```
master:~$ kubectl version --short
Flag --short has been deprecated, and will be removed in the future. The --short output will become the default.
Client Version: v1.24.3
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
Server Version: v1.24.3
```

my jenkinsfile run these agents:

```
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: kubectl
            image: joshendriks/alpine-k8s
            command:
            - /bin/cat
            tty: true
          - name: docker
            image: docker:latest
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true
            volumeMounts:
             - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
               name: docker-sock
          volumes:
          - name: docker-sock
            hostPath:
              path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

it gives my this error randomly:

```
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: not ready after 5000 MILLISECONDS
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.Utils.waitUntilReadyOrFail(Utils.java:181)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.core.v1.PodOperationsImpl.exec(PodOperationsImpl.java:332)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.core.v1.PodOperationsImpl.exec(PodOperationsImpl.java:85)
    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator$1.doLaunch(ContainerExecDecorator.java:425)
    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator$1.launch(ContainerExecDecorator.java:328)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:509)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.launchWithCookie(BourneShellScript.java:176)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask.launch(FileMonitoringTask.java:132)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.start(DurableTaskStep.java:324)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:322)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:163)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:158)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:46)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor187.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:187)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:420)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:95)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:294)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

and it's happening randomly:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can find answers in this post in [Git fabric8io issues](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/3795)

Comment: Did you find a solution? If so, please can you post it here? We are experiencing the exact same problem. Thanks!

Comment: @YoniRabinovitch I was getting a very similar error to this recently in a build pipeline that was utilizing parallel stages. I was able to get the build going again by requesting an additional CPU and an extra 2GB of memory for my container in the .yml file. Not sure if it will help you but it fixed my issues. Best of Luck

Comment: Unfortunately nothing worked for me and the issue still exists

Comment: @YoniRabinovitch did you find a solution. I tried everything and the issue still exist.

Comment: @EslamAli Upgrading to the latest version of the kubernetes plugin improved the situation.  It introduces a retry on these timeouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest version of the kubernetes plugin improved the situation. It introduces a retry on these timeouts. Thanks to @YoniRabinovitch to figure it out.

Comment: By latest version, can you please supply the exact version you used which included the retries? It would be externally helpful to know when the retry logic was introduced. Thanks.

Comment: sorry for late replay I have another issue with ingress that I can't solve since then. currently I'm using Kubernetes plugin Version 3704.va_08f0206b_95e